# Does setting an object to nil flag it for garbage collection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, garbage-collection

When I set an `object = nil`, will it be garbage collected or do I have to *release* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current iOS doesn't support garbage collection, so no.

However, if object is a @property of another object and is defined something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id object;
```

Then calling myObject.object = nil will autorelease the previous value of object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no garbage collection in Objective-C (on iOS as state by ThomasW).

If you create an object autorelease object, then the autorelease pool will clean up the object if its retain count hits 0.

All other object you should release your self.

Comment: To be pedantic, there is garbage collection for the 64-bit version of Objective-C running on Mac OS X, but not elsewhere.

Comment: @Thom That’s wrong. Garbage collection is available for 32-bit applications on Mac OS X.

Comment: @Bavarious Looks like you're right. I wonder where I got the impression it was 64-bit only.

Comment: @Thom Maybe you were thinking of the non-fragile ABI.